# returning 8 closest cgfloat from a table lookup based on a cgfloat

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm

I am trying to create this method. Let's call this

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getEightClosestSwatchesFor:(CGFloat)hue
{
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"festival101" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myFile];

for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray) 
{
    NSLog(@"[plistData valueForKey:aKey] string] is %f", [[dict valueForKey:@"hue"] floatValue]) ;

}

return myArray;
```

}

pretty much, I am passing a cgfloat to this method which then needs to check a plist file which have hue key for 100 elements. I need to compare my hue with all of the hues and get 8 most closest hue and finally wrap these into an array and return this.

What would be most efficient way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the plist just have hue values, or does it have colors? The answers will look very different if you need to actually compare the colors for similarity.

Comment: hue/brightness/saturation. hues are pretty basic but it's just a start. What would you recommend?

Comment: "It's complicated". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my method if anyone is interested. Feel free to comment on it.

```
-(NSArray*)eightClosestSwatchesForHue:(CGFloat)hue
{

NSMutableArray *updatedArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"festival101" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myFile];



for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray) 
{
    CGFloat differenceHue = fabs(hue - [[dict valueForKey:@"hue"] floatValue]);
    //create  a KVA for the differenceHue here and  then add it to the dictionary and add this dictionary to the array.
    NSDictionary* tempDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [dict valueForKey:@"id"], @"id",
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:differenceHue], @"differenceHue",
     [dict valueForKey:@"color"], @"color",
    nil];

    [updatedArray addObject:tempDict]; 
}



//now we have an array of dictioneries with values we want. we need to sort this from little to big now.
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"differenceHue"  ascending:YES];
[updatedArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

[descriptor release];

//now get the first 8 elements and get rid of the remaining.
NSArray *finalArray = [updatedArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,8)];
[updatedArray release];
return finalArray;
}
```